# Is it possible to run rails app from a remote database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been searching for a solution couple of days and done with nothing.
Is it really impossible to run rails app from a remote database?

My case:
I have a database located on one of my offices as a local server.
I need my rails app(hosted on some hosting service) to connect and run from this private database on this private server.

Is there really a solution or workaround?

And not related to rails but is it possible with django framework. just out of curiosity.

Thank you all very much for the answers!

Comment: in your `database.yml` you can set up `url` attribute where you add url to your remote DB

Answer (score 1):

You can set host in your databasey.yml like:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: prod_db
  username: prod_user
  password: prod_pwd
  host: 10.10.10.10
  port: 5432
  pool: 3
```

But you should have static ip or you can create VPN between two servers

Comment: Okay, now should I play with port forwarding to this specific server in my network? Or static up should be enough? My mysql port is 3306.

Comment: I don't know specification your network, and I don't know which server and os you use for db. But yes, in most cases you should or open ports in server or do port forwarding in router.